# Rails: returning data to a file if success

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

I'm new to rails. I have an email input form, and I'm adding validation.
This is my controller:

```
 @email=params[:email]
 @BetaSignup = BetaSignup.create!(:email => @email)
```

And my model:

```
class BetaSignup < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, :presence => true, :email => true
end
```

I want to then, depending on the result of @BetaSignup to tell the user whether it was an emails or not.

Is it correct to do as follows in my view?

```
if (<%- @BetaSignup %>) {
```

Yet this doesn't work, and the view file never even gets accessed because the data above the line above (which clears the input field) doesn't happen (or maybe it doesn't happen because of the error)

Thoughts??

Answer (score 1):

You are using `create!` so the code will throw an exception if the record is invalid.

You could continue using that and rescuing the exception, or you could change that to not throw an exception and check the object afterwards:

```
@BetaSignup = BetaSignup.create(:email => @email)
if (@BetaSignup)
  //validations passed
else
  //validations failed
  @BetaSignup.errors // <-- validation errors are here
end
```